# Highlight text in Python Idle

Tags: python, python-idle

So I'm revising my code and I'm wishing I could highlight just the part where I made a mistake so it would be easy to spot the mistake if I come back to it and learn from it....

```py
#Don't Need True When Using In
gifts = []
l =  input ("What do you want to have?")
gifts.append(l)
while l.lower() != "nothing" :
    l = input ("Anything else?").lower()
    gifts.append(l)                     
a = gifts.index("nothing")
gifts = gifts[:a] + gifts[a+1:]

if "soup" in gifts ==True:

    b = gifts.index('soup')
    gifts = gifts[:b]+["broth"]+gifts[b+1:]
for x in gifts:
    print ("I can give you", end= " ")
    print (x, end = " ")
    print ("if you wish..")
```

I trapped it in a triple quote to preserve it so everything is green right now. Can I make just the (if "soup" in gifts == True:) part a different color somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what i know you can't, but another solution would be to write
a
`# TODO - fix stuff on the left --------------------------------`
comment on the right side of this line